# How I know if my Tor installation is serving as a relay user or not?

Tags: tor

I just install this packet on my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop system for a university project and I want to know if my computer is serving as a relay client for the Tor network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is to ask yourself if you edited the configuration file `torrc`. If not,  Tor will be running as client (not relay).

If you did it depends on what settings you made. One easy way to check it is visiting https://atlas.torproject.org or https://globe.torproject.org. if you enter your ip address it looks into the database of all relays and tells you if your ip address is listed as relay. If it happened in the past go to https://exonerator.torproject.org and enter ip address and date. The site will tell you if this address was a relay at that point in time.